inverse limit of topological spaces and continuous function
Let $(X_i, f_{ij})$ be an inverse system of topological spaces, where the maps $f_{ij}: X_j \to X_i$ are continuous for all $i \leq j$ in the set $I$. Let $X$ be the inverse limit of this system, meaning that $X$ is a topological space along with projection maps $\pi_i: X \to X_i$ for each $i \in I$, such that for all $i \leq j$, the following diagram commutes:
$
f_{ij} \circ \pi_j = \pi_i.
$
(See general definition in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit for a commutative diagram).
Now, suppose we have a family of continuous functions $\{h_i: X_i \to \mathbb{R}\}_{i \in I}$ that satisfy the compatibility condition $h_i \circ f_{ij} = h_j$ for all $j \leq i$. Define a function $h: X \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$
h(x) = h_i \circ \pi_i(x)
$
for any (i \in I).
Due to the commutative diagrams, it is clear that $h(x)$ does not depend on the choice of $i$, so $h$ is well-defined.
My question is:
Is the function $h: X \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous?
Thank you!

You can view $h$ as a map induced between inverse systems. As such it is continuous, see pg.101 of Engelking's book and especially the discussion on pgs.103-104. Unfortunately, this question is not really research level, and I'd recommend that stack exchange would be a better home for it.

Thanks for your quick answer !!!

Yes, it's continuous because it's equal to $h_i \circ \pi_i$ for some $i$. The composite of two continuous maps is continuous. No need for fancy tech :)
